# Next level doesn't unlock even though I completed the preceding level

Tags: android, bad-piggies

As the title says, the next level (22 in the screenshot below) is still locked although I've accomplished the preceding level (21 in the below screenshot) as shown by the below screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the game]

BTW, I'm on the second stage (Rise and Shine) and this is the first time in seeing this problem happen.

- Why doesn't the next level unlock?
- How do I unlock the next level?

**Edit**: This happened in the next stage too (When Pigs Fly) and all the stages after it.

Comment: And Will uninstalling the game and then reinstalling it lose my progress?

Comment: Yes, your progress is not synced to the cloud, so you will lose it. There is a way to back up your files via a file manager, but it may very well preserve the error, of course.

Comment: It is not uncommon for developers to "force" you to watch adds. If you consider that the game is free, and they have to make money from it, it is a common tactic. I highly doubt there is a legitimate way to get around this. If you fix the problem by watching a 15 second ad, just watch the 15 second ad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround on this problem but it is an annoying and irritating one.

## Steps to counter the problem:

1. Connect your mobile to the internet (I used WiFi)
2. Open Bad Piggies
3. Open the stage on which the problem happens
4. Press the back button
5. Open the same stage again
6. You'll find a video icon on the locked level:

   [image: SCREENSHOT]

   Click that locked level, watch the 15 second ad, and Bingo! The level is unlocked!

But...After completing this unlocked level, **the problem rises once again** and the next level remains locked even though I completed the preceding level! :-( These steps need to be followed again to unlock the next level. This is very annoying and irritating and that's why I'm waiting for a better answer here...

Comment: Oh man, that is new... I've played Piggies some time ago, and actually used to disconnect WiFi to avoid the advertisements. It is as if they have found this loophole and deliberately blocked it. :-(

Comment: "bug" that forces you to watch ads... hmmm... sounds suspicious... *looks at developer*